# Android BLE Advertising UUID Length differs on different SDK level?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I want to broadcast some data via BLE.

The addServiceData function takes a ParcelUuid and the data.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html

I tested it on my **Android 7.0** Smartphone and the Uuid got shrinked down to **16 bits**.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426

> While this utility creates a 128-bit UUID, the Android system only
>   uses 16-bit UUIDs for advertisement and will automatically adjust a
>   128-bit UUID to conform.

This is fine, cause I need the bandwidth for the data I send. But the **same** App sends the **full 128 bit Uuid** on an **Android 8.1** device.

I dont understand this and I want my app to send always the 16 bit Uuid.
I found no option to choose the length of the Uuid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 16-bit Bluetooth UUID is a shortcut for:

```
0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

… where `xxxx` is the 16 bits. For example, if you want to advertise a `BEEF` UUID, I believe you need to pass `0000BEEF-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` to `AdvertiseData.Builder`.

Further down the stack, Android should recognize this as a 16-bit Bluetooth UUID, and broadcast only the two bytes. The relevant code is in the [`AdvertiseHelper`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/2fc4c7344bf006dea8aefc8e717a38a3253fb789/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/AdvertiseHelper.java#107) and [`BluetoothUuid`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c9bcf869db80d8b4b94994d2438dd51e626ad78e/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothUuid.java#309) classes in the AOSP:

```
public static byte[] uuidToBytes(ParcelUuid uuid) {
    if (uuid == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("uuid cannot be null");
    }

    if (is16BitUuid(uuid)) {
        byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[UUID_BYTES_16_BIT];
        int uuidVal = getServiceIdentifierFromParcelUuid(uuid);
        uuidBytes[0] = (byte) (uuidVal & 0xFF);
        uuidBytes[1] = (byte) ((uuidVal & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        return uuidBytes;
    }

    ...
```

I guess this behavior may have changed between 7.0 and 8.1. Looks like previously, they may have been converting the 128-bit UUID to a 16-bit UUID no matter what. Now, looks like it'll correctly only do so if the 128-bit UUID follows the Bluetooth standard/notation.